# Expose one config file to be read by N Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, config

I'm developing a Windows Store App that will be deployed to (about) 50 computers. This app is downloading data from a WebApi. The WebApi is on a server, that has an IP. I need to set this IP into the App. Each App will have the SAME IP to refer to.

The server's IP may change and I don't want to rebuild and redeploy the App. I want to just change the config file (with the IP inside) in one shot. My first thought was about creating a config file and then edit it via PowerShell with a script.

Is there a better solution? This solution isn't very good to me because if the App in the future will be deployed to some phone or Raspberry, it would be very difficult to update the config file like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use http://www.noip.com/
Instead of using an IP, you will have a hostname, which you can be updated every time the ip changes.